# Adaptive Threshold error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'

Tags: python, opencv, keras, adaptive-threshold

I am working on pre-trained vgg16 model, for that I need to have input size of image file to be (224,224,3).

The code I am working on is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = image.load_img('abc.jpg',target_size=(224,224))
img = image.img_to_array(img)

print(img.shape)
## output : (224,224,3)
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#plt.imshow(img_grey)

th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_grey,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(th3)
```

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-2a8a27b965ed> in <module>
     17 #plt.imshow(img_grey)
     18 
---> 19 th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_grey,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
     20 plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
     21 plt.imshow(th3)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1627: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'
```

Help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error says the solution: `src.type() == CV_8UC1` meaning you need to set your image type to the `uint8` [source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)

So if you redefine your `img` variable:

```py
img = image.img_to_array(img, dtype='uint8')
```

Problem will be solved but I have a question.

Why do you define the below statement?

```py
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

How do you know `load_img` loads the image in `BGR` fashion?

We know opencv loads the image `cv2.imread` in `BGR` fashion.

The statement is wrong, since `load_img` loads the image in `RGB` format [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img)

Therefore the correct statement will be:

```py
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

or you can do:

```py
img = image.load_img('15f8U.png', grayscale=True, target_size=(224, 224))
```

Correct Code:

```py
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = image.load_img('15f8U.png', grayscale=True, target_size=(224, 224))
img = image.img_to_array(img, dtype='uint8')

print(img.shape)
## output : (224,224,3)
#plt.imshow(img_grey)

th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(th3, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

`cv2.adaptive_threshold` needs an input array of dtype `uint8`:

```
img_grey = img_grey.astype(np.uint8)

th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_grey...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... `img2 = img.astype(np.uint8); type(img2) -> numpy.ndarray; img2.dtype -> dtype('uint8')` and yet I still get `src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'`...

Answer (score 6):

@bakuriu thresholding works on grayscaled images only, you need to convert the image to grayscale first and the the adaptiveThreshold

```
img = image.img_to_array(img2, dtype='uint8')
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_grey,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```